# According to Marx, was slavery in the US in the 19th century feudal, pre-feudal or capitalist?

Tags: united-states, marxism, slavery

The political regime in the US had few feudal traits. On the other hand it had similarity to serfdom in Russia. So, was it classified as feudal vestige or something else?

Comment: Capitalist, but his writing on slavery is varied: see https://monthlyreview.org/2020/07/01/marx-and-slavery/

Answer (score 2):

In Marxism, feudalism and capitalism are distinguished by their mode of production. Under feudalism, that mode is tied to land (real property) and land is controlled by an aristocracy. Land is allocated into hereditary fiefs which have the primary purpose of maintaining a standing military to secure the fief and provide troops for the central authority. Laborers were largely free to produce what they wanted and only required to send the feudal lord taxes, levies, or rents, or in some cases be pressed into military duty. These could be excessive demands, obviously, but ultimately the lord and the laborer shared a common interest in production, since the laborer created product for his own use and passed a portion on to the land owner. That being said, every fief needs laborers to make the owned-land productive, because a deficit of laborers impacts revenue and makes it impossible to maintain a standing armed force. So some states created serf rules, where certain kinds of laborers could not leave one fief for another seeking better opportunities. This is effectively the same as modern immigration rules which control and limit what people can enter or leave a nation-state, except that it involved internal borders instead of external ones.

In the transition to capitalism, the mode of production ceased being directly tied to real property and instead tied itself to commodities (as abstraction of real products). This obviated the need for fiefs, or any territory that must be physically maintained and defended. Real property became fungible, and the new mode involved paying a local government to secure land-use rights and to provide and control a steady stream of laborers. This had two implications:

1. Laborers no longer had any direct interest in the commodity being produced, but merely provided labor-power for a flat wage, and...
2. Laborers were themselves fungible: interchangeable and easily replaced.

In short, labor in the capitalist system became a commodity in its own right, with capital investors and local governments negotiating labor supply for specific projects and industries. And once labor became a commodity, it was a short step to chattel slavery where individual laborers were bought and sold on the open market.

The important point here is that serf were largely free, or at least as free as medieval peasants could expect to be. They might have been restricted to a specified land, but they could marry, have drinks with friends, join a guild, and to the extent possible enjoy the fruits of their own labor. Slaves could not. From the perspective of a slave owner, a slave was a capital investment in livestock (like buying a horse or a cow). Livestock does not enjoy the fruits of its own labor.

Comment: *labor in the capitalist system became a commodity ... And once labor became a commodity, it was a short step to chattel slavery where individual laborers were bought and sold on the open market.*  This reads as "capitalism leads to slavery".  The ancient Greeks and Romans were all capitalists?  Along with Babylonians, ancient Persians?  And ancient Chinese?  Mayan?  Comanche were capitalists?  Pretty much the only place in the capitalist world that fought against the ending of chattal slavery was the Confederate States of America, where slavery was tied to the farming of real property.

Comment: @JustMe: Sigh... I knew someone would drag out that old saw. Slavery in the ancient world was an entirely different phenomenon: generally spoils of conquest who were taken as courtesans, pressed into the military or fighting sports, or used as serfs or household servants. Pre-feudal societies lacked the social institutions necessary for large-scale chattel slavery (or a production mode that required it), so slaves were more a mark of status (and treated as such) than work animals. Capitalism created the chattel slave market. The same word can mean different things in different contexts, yah?

Comment: Also good to note that the above is, to my understanding, meant to illustrate the Marxist view on the topic, which doesn't necessarily reflect all the historical circumstances. History is complicated, and things like slavery and serfdom have taken all sorts of different forms depending on time period and society, often co-existing in some form. Even in Rome there was a big difference between slaves working in mines and farms, those working as household slaves, to educated slaves running businesses, household finances or working as teachers, to prize fighters.

Comment: @Anixx: read my comment again; you've misunderstood. And no, US slavery was *institutionalized chattel* slavery, which the Romans didn't practice.

Comment: @TedWrigley for all I know, they had institutionalized chattel slavery.

Comment: @Anixx: Well, no one  of us is going to have to look it up, just to be sure, so I guess I'll do that tomorrow. Not exactly how I planned my Christmas… lol.